# C# datagridview order columns value bug

Tags: c#, datagridview, header, datagridviewcolumn, tab-ordering

I am New In C#

I have a problem in My datagrideview i cant make the Column [Size] to be order in the right way (KB >> MB >> GB) or (GB >> MB >> KB) by clicking the Header By the Left Mouse

the value in the Column [Size] is **nvarchar(60)** and all added as text (0.1 KB or 2 MB ....etc)

how can i do that ?

[image: I want to know how can i order the KB MB GB]

[image: From My Database]

Comment: It is possible to change the type of the size column?

Comment: yes i can do it

Comment: what is type of data source?

Comment: this date will be enter by the user the size of the file .. is that what you mean ?

Comment: I think you need additional method for natural sorting file size column in `DataTable` and handle sorting with `ColumnHeaderMouseClick` event. Is that the file size retrieved from actual file in disk or just obtained without calculating actual file?

Comment: no the size will be enter by the user as text  .. i will make the size enter in textbox  and the KB ,MB , GB by choose it from comboBox  and add it in column [Size]

Answer (score 0):

Handle the `SortCompare` even like this:

```
private void dataGridView1_SortCompare(object sender,
            DataGridViewSortCompareEventArgs e)
{
    // Sort the size column
    if (e.Column.Name == "Size")
    {
        e.SortResult = new SizeComparer().Compare(
            e.CellValue1.ToString(), e.CellValue2.ToString());
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

It will use the code below to do the comparison for sorting. This code does a very simple thing: It takes the last two characters (MB, GB) etc. and based on that determines the multiplier. Then it takes that and multiplies it by the number before the unit. For example for `1.0 KB` it will do `1 * 1000` and then compare based on that:

```
public class ItemSize
{
    public string Unit { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}
public class SizeComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        var itemX =  new ItemSize { Unit = x.Substring(x.Length - 2), Value = double.Parse(x.Substring(0, x.Length - 2)) };
        var itemY = new ItemSize { Unit = y.Substring(y.Length - 2), Value = double.Parse(y.Substring(0, y.Length - 2)) };
        SetItemSize(itemX);
        SetItemSize(itemY);

        return itemX.Value.CompareTo(itemY.Value);

    }

    private void SetItemSize(ItemSize item)
    {
        switch (item.Unit)
        {
            case "KB":
                item.Value *= 1000;
                break;
            case "MB":
                item.Value *= 1000000;
                break;
            case "GB":
                item.Value *= 1000000000;
                break;
            // Add all the other cases
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("Looks like you missed one...");
        }
    }
}
```

Please make sure to do error handling. Use `double.TryParse` if there are cases that parsing can fail.

Comment: The type or namespace name 'IComparer<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) ..... iam sorry i am new in c# how can i fix this ?

Comment: You need to import: put this at the top: `using System.Collections.Generic`.

Comment: That's not possible. I tested that code. The issue is elsewhere. And what do you mean not working? Did you add this code to the event handler?

Comment: maybe if there is way to convert all sizes to KB , will this make it easier to sort ??